# How do I calculate percentiles with python/numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, quantile, percentile

Is there a convenient way to calculate percentiles for a sequence or single-dimensional `numpy` array?

I am looking for something similar to Excel's percentile function.

Comment: A related question on computation of percentiles from frequencies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070086/percentiles-from-counts-of-values

Comment: A related question for `pandas` data frame: [python - Find percentile stats of a given column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581893/find-percentile-stats-of-a-given-column)

Answer (score 391, accepted):

NumPy has [`np.percentile()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html).

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
p = np.percentile(a, 50)  # return 50th percentile, i.e. median.
```

```
>>> print(p)
3.0
```

---

SciPy has [`scipy.stats.scoreatpercentile()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.scoreatpercentile.html#scipy.stats.scoreatpercentile), in addition to many [other statistical goodies](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html).

Comment: Thank you! So that's where it's been hiding. I was aware of scipy but I guess I assumed simple things like percentiles would be built into numpy.

Comment: By now, a percentile function exists in numpy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html

Comment: You can use it as an aggregation function as well, e.g. to compute the tenth percentile of each group of a value column by key, use `df.groupby('key')[['value']].agg(lambda g: np.percentile(g, 10))`

Comment: Note that SciPy recommends to use np.percentile for NumPy 1.9 and higher

Answer (score 88):

By the way, there is [a pure-Python implementation of percentile function](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511478-finding-the-percentile-of-the-values/), in case one doesn't want to depend on scipy.  The function is copied below:

```
## {{{ http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511478/ (r1)
import math
import functools

def percentile(N, percent, key=lambda x:x):
    """
    Find the percentile of a list of values.

    @parameter N - is a list of values. Note N MUST BE already sorted.
    @parameter percent - a float value from 0.0 to 1.0.
    @parameter key - optional key function to compute value from each element of N.

    @return - the percentile of the values
    """
    if not N:
        return None
    k = (len(N)-1) * percent
    f = math.floor(k)
    c = math.ceil(k)
    if f == c:
        return key(N[int(k)])
    d0 = key(N[int(f)]) * (c-k)
    d1 = key(N[int(c)]) * (k-f)
    return d0+d1

# median is 50th percentile.
median = functools.partial(percentile, percent=0.5)
## end of http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511478/ }}}
```

Comment: I am the author of the above recipe. A commenter in ASPN has pointed out the original code has a bug. The formula should be d0 = key(N[int(f)]) * (c-k); d1 = key(N[int(c)]) * (k-f). It has been corrected on ASPN.

Comment: How does `percentile` know what to use for `N`? It isn't specified in the function call.

Comment: for those who didn't even read the code, before using it, N must be sorted

Comment: I'm confused by the lambda expression. What does it do and how does it do it? I know what lambda expression are so I am not asking what lambda is. I am asking what does this specific lambda expression do and how is it doing it, step-by-step? Thanks!

Comment: The lambda function lets you transform the data in `N` before calculating a percentile. Say you actually have a list of tuples `N = [(1, 2), (3, 1), ..., (5, 1)]` and you want to get the percentile of the _first_ element of the tuples, then you choose `key=lambda x: x[0]`.

You could also apply some (order-changing) transformation to the list elements before calculating a percentile.

Comment: @dsanchez In this case, the lambda can be used to map the data being passed in to values that can be evaluated as a percentile. In theory, you could pass the function a sorted dictionary of words and use the lambda to map the entries as word lengths, sums of ASCII values, etc. The lambda takes each entry x and maps it to a new value. The default parameter passed here just maps each entry as itself (x:x).

Answer (score 40):

Starting `Python 3.8`, the standard library comes with the [`quantiles`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html?highlight=quantiles#statistics.quantiles) function  as part of the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html) module:

```
from statistics import quantiles

quantiles([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], n=100)
# [0.06, 0.12, 0.18, 0.24, 0.3, 0.36, 0.42, 0.48, 0.54, 0.6, 0.66, 0.72, 0.78, 0.84, 0.9, 0.96, 1.02, 1.08, 1.14, 1.2, 1.26, 1.32, 1.38, 1.44, 1.5, 1.56, 1.62, 1.68, 1.74, 1.8, 1.86, 1.92, 1.98, 2.04, 2.1, 2.16, 2.22, 2.28, 2.34, 2.4, 2.46, 2.52, 2.58, 2.64, 2.7, 2.76, 2.82, 2.88, 2.94, 3.0, 3.06, 3.12, 3.18, 3.24, 3.3, 3.36, 3.42, 3.48, 3.54, 3.6, 3.66, 3.72, 3.78, 3.84, 3.9, 3.96, 4.02, 4.08, 4.14, 4.2, 4.26, 4.32, 4.38, 4.44, 4.5, 4.56, 4.62, 4.68, 4.74, 4.8, 4.86, 4.92, 4.98, 5.04, 5.1, 5.16, 5.22, 5.28, 5.34, 5.4, 5.46, 5.52, 5.58, 5.64, 5.7, 5.76, 5.82, 5.88, 5.94]
quantiles([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], n=100)[49] # 50th percentile (e.g median)
# 3.0
```

---

[`quantiles`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html?highlight=quantiles#statistics.quantiles) returns for a given distribution `dist` a list of `n - 1` cut points separating the `n` quantile intervals (division of `dist` into `n` continuous intervals with equal probability):

> statistics.quantiles(dist, *, n=4, method='exclusive')

where `n`, in our case (`percentiles`) is `100`.

Comment: Just a note. With method="exclusive" p99 can be larger than maximum value in original list. If it is not what you want, i.e. you want p100 = max, then use method="inclusive".

Answer (score 37):

```
import numpy as np
a = [154, 400, 1124, 82, 94, 108]
print np.percentile(a,95) # gives the 95th percentile
```

Answer (score 28):

Here's how to do it without numpy, using only python to calculate the percentile.

```
import math

def percentile(data, perc: int):
    size = len(data)
    return sorted(data)[int(math.ceil((size * perc) / 100)) - 1]

percentile([10.0, 9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0], 90)
# 9.0
percentile([142, 232, 290, 120, 274, 123, 146, 113, 272, 119, 124, 277, 207], 50)
# 146
```

Comment: Yes, you have to sort the list before:
mylist=sorted(...)

Answer (score 13):

The definition of percentile I usually see expects as a result the value from the supplied list below which P percent of values are found... which means the result must be from the set, not an interpolation between set elements.  To get that, you can use a simpler function.

```
def percentile(N, P):
    """
    Find the percentile of a list of values

    @parameter N - A list of values.  N must be sorted.
    @parameter P - A float value from 0.0 to 1.0

    @return - The percentile of the values.
    """
    n = int(round(P * len(N) + 0.5))
    return N[n-1]

# A = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
# B = (15, 20, 35, 40, 50)
#
# print percentile(A, P=0.3)
# 4
# print percentile(A, P=0.8)
# 9
# print percentile(B, P=0.3)
# 20
# print percentile(B, P=0.8)
# 50
```

If you would rather get the value from the supplied list at or below which P percent of values are found, then use this simple modification:

```
def percentile(N, P):
    n = int(round(P * len(N) + 0.5))
    if n > 1:
        return N[n-2]
    else:
        return N[0]
```

Or with the simplification suggested by @ijustlovemath:

```
def percentile(N, P):
    n = max(int(round(P * len(N) + 0.5)), 2)
    return N[n-2]
```

Comment: thanks, I also expect percentile/median to result actual values from the sets and not interpolations

Comment: Hi @mpounsett. Thank you for the upper code. Why does your percentile always return integer values? The percentile function should return the N-th percentile of a list of values, and this can be a float number too.
For example, the Excel ```PERCENTILE``` function returns the following percentiles for your upper examples: ```3.7 = percentile(A, P=0.3)```,```0.82 = percentile(A, P=0.8)```, ```20 = percentile(B, P=0.3)```, ```42 = percentile(B, P=0.8)```.

Comment: It's explained in the first sentence.  The more common definition of percentile is that it is the number in a series below which P percent of values in the series are found.   Since that is the index number of an item in a list, it cannot be a float.

Comment: This doesn't work for the 0'th percentile. It returns the maximum value. A quick fix would be to wrap the `n = int(...)` in a `max(int(...), 1)` function

Comment: To clarify, do you mean in the second example?  I get 0 rather than the maximum value.  The bug is actually in the else clause.. I printed the index number rather than the value I intended to.  Wrapping the assignment of 'n' in a max() call would also fix it, but you'd want the second value to be 2, not 1.  You could then eliminate the entire if/else structure and just print the result of N[n-2].   0th percentile works fine in the first example, returning '1' and '15' respectively.

Comment: sorry for the downvote. Accidental. Made on my phone without noticing it. it is now locked!!

Answer (score 6):

check for scipy.stats module:

```
 scipy.stats.scoreatpercentile
```

Answer (score 3):

A convenient way to calculate percentiles for a one-dimensional numpy sequence or matrix is by using numpy.percentile <https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html>. Example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
p50 = np.percentile(a, 50) # return 50th percentile, e.g median.
p90 = np.percentile(a, 90) # return 90th percentile.
print('median = ',p50,' and p90 = ',p90) # median =  5.0  and p90 =  9.0
```

However, if there is any NaN value in your data, the above function will not be useful. The recommended function to use in that case is the numpy.nanpercentile <https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanpercentile.html> function:

```
import numpy as np

a_NaN = np.array([0.,1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.,10.])
a_NaN[0] = np.nan
print('a_NaN',a_NaN)
p50 = np.nanpercentile(a_NaN, 50) # return 50th percentile, e.g median.
p90 = np.nanpercentile(a_NaN, 90) # return 90th percentile.
print('median = ',p50,' and p90 = ',p90) # median =  5.5  and p90 =  9.1
```

In the two options presented above, you can still choose the interpolation mode. Follow the examples below for easier understanding.

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
print('percentiles using default interpolation')
p10 = np.percentile(b, 10) # return 10th percentile.
p50 = np.percentile(b, 50) # return 50th percentile, e.g median.
p90 = np.percentile(b, 90) # return 90th percentile.
print('p10 = ',p10,', median = ',p50,' and p90 = ',p90)
#p10 =  1.9 , median =  5.5  and p90 =  9.1

print('percentiles using interpolation = ', "linear")
p10 = np.percentile(b, 10,interpolation='linear') # return 10th percentile.
p50 = np.percentile(b, 50,interpolation='linear') # return 50th percentile, e.g median.
p90 = np.percentile(b, 90,interpolation='linear') # return 90th percentile.
print('p10 = ',p10,', median = ',p50,' and p90 = ',p90)
#p10 =  1.9 , median =  5.5  and p90 =  9.1

print('percentiles using interpolation = ', "lower")
p10 = np.percentile(b, 10,interpolation='lower') # return 10th percentile.
p50 = np.percentile(b, 50,interpolation='lower') # return 50th percentile, e.g median.
p90 = np.percentile(b, 90,interpolation='lower') # return 90th percentile.
print('p10 = ',p10,', median = ',p50,' and p90 = ',p90)
#p10 =  1 , median =  5  and p90 =  9

print('percentiles using interpolation = ', "higher")
p10 = np.percentile(b, 10,interpolation='higher') # return 10th percentile.
p50 = np.percentile(b, 50,interpolation='higher') # return 50th percentile, e.g median.
p90 = np.percentile(b, 90,interpolation='higher') # return 90th percentile.
print('p10 = ',p10,', median = ',p50,' and p90 = ',p90)
#p10 =  2 , median =  6  and p90 =  10

print('percentiles using interpolation = ', "midpoint")
p10 = np.percentile(b, 10,interpolation='midpoint') # return 10th percentile.
p50 = np.percentile(b, 50,interpolation='midpoint') # return 50th percentile, e.g median.
p90 = np.percentile(b, 90,interpolation='midpoint') # return 90th percentile.
print('p10 = ',p10,', median = ',p50,' and p90 = ',p90)
#p10 =  1.5 , median =  5.5  and p90 =  9.5

print('percentiles using interpolation = ', "nearest")
p10 = np.percentile(b, 10,interpolation='nearest') # return 10th percentile.
p50 = np.percentile(b, 50,interpolation='nearest') # return 50th percentile, e.g median.
p90 = np.percentile(b, 90,interpolation='nearest') # return 90th percentile.
print('p10 = ',p10,', median = ',p50,' and p90 = ',p90)
#p10 =  2 , median =  5  and p90 =  9
```

If your input array only consists of integer values, you might be interested in the percentil answer as an integer. If so, choose interpolation mode such as ‘lower’, ‘higher’, or ‘nearest’.

Comment: Thanks For mentioning the `interpolation` option since without it the outputs were misleading

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the percentile of a series, run:

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata
import numpy as np

def calc_percentile(a, method='min'):
    if isinstance(a, list):
        a = np.asarray(a)
    return rankdata(a, method=method) / float(len(a))
```

For example:

```
a = range(20)
print {val: round(percentile, 3) for val, percentile in zip(a, calc_percentile(a))}
>>> {0: 0.05, 1: 0.1, 2: 0.15, 3: 0.2, 4: 0.25, 5: 0.3, 6: 0.35, 7: 0.4, 8: 0.45, 9: 0.5, 10: 0.55, 11: 0.6, 12: 0.65, 13: 0.7, 14: 0.75, 15: 0.8, 16: 0.85, 17: 0.9, 18: 0.95, 19: 1.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

**In case you need the answer to be a member of the input numpy array:**

Just to add that the percentile function in numpy by default calculates the output as a linear weighted average of the two neighboring entries in the input vector.  In some cases people may want the returned percentile to be an actual element of the vector, in this case, from v1.9.0 onwards you can use the "interpolation" option, with either "lower", "higher" or "nearest".

```
import numpy as np
x=np.random.uniform(10,size=(1000))-5.0

np.percentile(x,70) # 70th percentile

2.075966046220879

np.percentile(x,70,interpolation="nearest")

2.0729677997904314
```

The latter is an actual entry in the vector, while the former is a linear interpolation of two vector entries that border the percentile

Answer (score 1):

for a series: used describe functions

suppose you have df with following columns sales and id. you want to calculate percentiles for sales then it works like this,

```
df['sales'].describe(percentiles = [0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1])

0.0: .0: minimum
1: maximum 
0.1 : 10th percentile and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

I bootstrap the data and then plotted out the confidence interval for 10 samples.   The confidence interval shows the range where the probabilities will fall between 5 percent and 95 percent probability.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import seaborn as sns
 import numpy as np
 import json
 import dc_stat_think as dcst

 data = [154, 400, 1124, 82, 94, 108]
 #print (np.percentile(data,[0.5,95])) # gives the 95th percentile

 bs_data = dcst.draw_bs_reps(data, np.mean, size=6*10)

 #print(np.reshape(bs_data,(24,6)))

 x= np.linspace(1,6,6)
 print(x)
 for (item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6) in bs_data.reshape((10,6)):
     line_data=[item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6]
     ci=np.percentile(line_data,[.025,.975])
     mean_avg=np.mean(line_data)
     fig, ax = plt.subplots()
     ax.plot(x,line_data)
     ax.fill_between(x, (line_data-ci[0]), (line_data+ci[1]), color='b', alpha=.1)
     ax.axhline(mean_avg,color='red')
     plt.show()
```