# Map each list value to its corresponding percentile

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, median, percentile

I'd like to create a function that takes a (sorted) list as its argument and outputs a list containing each element's corresponding percentile.

For example, `fn([1,2,3,4,17])` returns `[0.0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00]`.

Can anyone please either:

1. Help me correct my code below? OR
2. Offer a better alternative than my code for mapping values in a list to their corresponding percentiles?

My current code:

```
def median(mylist):
    length = len(mylist)
    if not length % 2:
        return (mylist[length / 2] + mylist[length / 2 - 1]) / 2.0
    return mylist[length / 2]

###############################################################################
# PERCENTILE FUNCTION
###############################################################################

def percentile(x):
    """
    Find the correspoding percentile of each value relative to a list of values.
    where x is the list of values
    Input list should already be sorted!
    """

    # sort the input list
    # list_sorted = x.sort()

    # count the number of elements in the list
    list_elementCount = len(x)

    #obtain set of values from list

    listFromSetFromList = list(set(x))

    # count the number of unique elements in the list
    list_uniqueElementCount = len(set(x))

    # define extreme quantiles
    percentileZero    = min(x)
    percentileHundred = max(x)

    # define median quantile
    mdn = median(x) 

    # create empty list to hold percentiles
    x_percentile = [0.00] * list_elementCount 

    # initialize unique count
    uCount = 0

    for i in range(list_elementCount):
        if x[i] == percentileZero:
            x_percentile[i] = 0.00
        elif x[i] == percentileHundred:
            x_percentile[i] = 1.00
        elif x[i] == mdn:
            x_percentile[i] = 0.50 
        else:
            subList_elementCount = 0
            for j in range(i):
                if x[j] < x[i]:
                    subList_elementCount = subList_elementCount + 1 
            x_percentile[i] = float(subList_elementCount / list_elementCount)
            #x_percentile[i] = float(len(x[x > listFromSetFromList[uCount]]) / list_elementCount)
            if i == 0:
                continue
            else:
                if x[i] == x[i-1]:
                    continue
                else:
                    uCount = uCount + 1
    return x_percentile
```

Currently, if I submit `percentile([1,2,3,4,17])`, the list `[0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0]` is returned.

Comment: I don't see any numpy or scipy use in your code, why use those tags?

Comment: When you say `each elements corresponding percentile`, do you mean `quintile`?

Comment: @Martijin Pieters: I included Numpy and SciPy as tags because I anticipate that someone may direct me to these libraries.

Comment: @Gerrat: Quintiles are a specific case of quantiles (i.e., the case where data are binned in five 'buckets', each representing 20% of the data). By quantiles, I intend to know which percentage of data is below a certain observed value (note that multiple instances of observed data could correspond to the same value; consider [1,2,3,4,4,4,4,17,17,21]).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374640/how-do-i-calculate-percentiles-with-python-numpy

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I think your example input/output does not correspond to typical ways of calculating percentile.  If you calculate the percentile as "proportion of data points strictly less than this value", then the top value should be 0.8 (since 4 of 5 values are less than the largest one).  If you calculate it as "percent of data points less than or equal to this value", then the bottom value should be 0.2 (since 1 of 5 values equals the smallest one).  Thus the percentiles would be `[0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8]` or `[0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]`.  Your definition seems to be "the number of data points strictly less than this value, considered as a proportion of the number of data points not equal to this value", but in my experience this is not a common definition (see for instance [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile)).

With the typical percentile definitions, the percentile of a data point is equal to its rank divided by the number of data points.  (See for instance [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11924/computing-percentile-rank-in-r) on Stats SE asking how to do the same thing in R.)  Differences in how to compute the percentile amount to differences in how to compute the rank (for instance, how to rank tied values).  The `scipy.stats.percentileofscore` function provides four ways of computing percentiles:

```
>>> x = [1, 1, 2, 2, 17]
>>> [stats.percentileofscore(x, a, 'rank') for a in x]
[30.0, 30.0, 70.0, 70.0, 100.0]
>>> [stats.percentileofscore(x, a, 'weak') for a in x]
[40.0, 40.0, 80.0, 80.0, 100.0]
>>> [stats.percentileofscore(x, a, 'strict') for a in x]
[0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0, 80.0]
>>> [stats.percentileofscore(x, a, 'mean') for a in x]
[20.0, 20.0, 60.0, 60.0, 90.0]
```

(I used a dataset containing ties to illustrate what happens in such cases.)

The "rank" method assigns tied groups a rank equal to the average of the ranks they would cover (i.e., a three-way tie for 2nd place gets a rank of 3 because it "takes up" ranks 2, 3 and 4).  The "weak" method assigns a percentile based on the proportion of data points less than or equal to a given point; "strict" is the same but counts proportion of points strictly less than the given point.  The "mean" method is the average of the latter two.

As Kevin H. Lin noted, calling `percentileofscore` in a loop is inefficient since it has to recompute the ranks on every pass.  However, these percentile calculations can be easily replicated using different ranking methods provided by [`scipy.stats.rankdata`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.rankdata.html), letting you calculate all the percentiles at once:

```
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> stats.rankdata(x, "average")/len(x)
array([ 0.3,  0.3,  0.7,  0.7,  1. ])
>>> stats.rankdata(x, 'max')/len(x)
array([ 0.4,  0.4,  0.8,  0.8,  1. ])
>>> (stats.rankdata(x, 'min')-1)/len(x)
array([ 0. ,  0. ,  0.4,  0.4,  0.8])
```

In the last case the ranks are adjusted down by one to make them start from 0 instead of 1.  (I've omitted "mean", but it could easily be obtained by averaging the results of the latter two methods.)

I did some timings.  With small data such as that in your example, using `rankdata` is somewhat slower than Kevin H. Lin's solution (presumably due to the overhead scipy incurs in converting things to numpy arrays under the hood) but faster than calling `percentileofscore` in a loop as in reptilicus's answer:

```
In [11]: %timeit [stats.percentileofscore(x, i) for i in x]
1000 loops, best of 3: 414 µs per loop

In [12]: %timeit list_to_percentiles(x)
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.1 µs per loop

In [13]: %timeit stats.rankdata(x, "average")/len(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.3 µs per loop
```

With a large dataset, however, the performance advantage of numpy takes effect and using `rankdata` is 10 times faster than Kevin's `list_to_percentiles`:

```
In [18]: x = np.random.randint(0, 10000, 1000)

In [19]: %timeit [stats.percentileofscore(x, i) for i in x]
1 loops, best of 3: 437 ms per loop

In [20]: %timeit list_to_percentiles(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.08 ms per loop

In [21]: %timeit stats.rankdata(x, "average")/len(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 102 µs per loop
```

This advantage will only become more pronounced on larger and larger datasets.

Comment: The advantages that you illustrate above have been confirmed.

Comment: Nice. If you look at the implementation of `scipy.stats.rankdata` (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.0/scipy/stats/mstats_basic.py#L212) you'll see that it makes use of `argsort()`. Their algorithm is essentially the same as mine, and the difference is entirely accounted for by the difference between Python lists and numpy arrays.

Answer (score 23):

I think you want [scipy.stats.percentileofscore](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html#scipy.stats.percentileofscore)

Example:

```
percentileofscore([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)
75.0
percentiles = [percentileofscore(data, i) for i in data]
```

Comment: Specifically, `[percentileofscore(score) for score in original_list]`.

Comment: @user1443118 and @Karl Knechtel: That does it.  Specific to my preferences, `[percentileofscore(data, i, 'weak') for i in data]` is what I'm looking for. Very Pythonic too.

Comment: I think this solution is O(n^2) which is not optimal.

Answer (score 15):

In terms of complexity, I think reptilicus's answer is not optimal. It takes O(n^2) time.

Here is a solution that takes O(n log n) time.

```
def list_to_percentiles(numbers):
    pairs = zip(numbers, range(len(numbers)))
    pairs.sort(key=lambda p: p[0])
    result = [0 for i in range(len(numbers))]
    for rank in xrange(len(numbers)):
        original_index = pairs[rank][1]
        result[original_index] = rank * 100.0 / (len(numbers)-1)
    return result
```

I'm not sure, but I think this is the optimal time complexity you can get. The rough reason I think it's optimal is because the information of all of the percentiles is essentially equivalent to the information of the sorted list, and you can't get better than O(n log n) for sorting.

EDIT: Depending on your definition of "percentile" this may not always give the correct result. See BrenBarn's answer for more explanation and for a better solution which makes use of scipy/numpy.

Comment: After I posted this answer, someone decided to serially downvote all of my SO posts. Not cool...

Comment: Thanks! You are very right that the answer using list comprehension with `scipy.stats.percentileofscore` is "not optimal." I timed both approaches with `timeit` and your function is great.

Comment: For Python3 add `list` around the `zip` and remove `x` from `xrange`

Answer (score 13):

#### Pure numpy version of Kevin's solution

As Kevin said, optimal solution works in O(n log(n)) time. Here is fast version of his code in `numpy`, which works almost the same time as `stats.rankdata`:

```
percentiles = numpy.argsort(numpy.argsort(array)) * 100. / (len(array) - 1)
```

PS. This is one if my favourite tricks in `numpy`.

Comment: This is not optimal, as duplicate values get ranked differently, as a result of the sort.

Answer (score 2):

this might look oversimplyfied but what about this:

```
def percentile(x):
    pc = float(1)/(len(x)-1)
    return ["%.2f"%(n*pc) for n, i in enumerate(x)]
```

EDIT:

```
def percentile(x):
    unique = set(x)
    mapping = {}
    pc = float(1)/(len(unique)-1)
    for n, i in enumerate(unique):
        mapping[i] = "%.2f"%(n*pc)
    return [mapping.get(el) for el in x]
```

Comment: Close, but this has the same problem as Aladdin's first attempt above.

Answer (score 2):

I tried Scipy's percentile score but it turned out to be very slow for one of my tasks. So, simply implemented it this way. Can be modified if a weak ranking is needed.

```
def assign_pct(X):
    mp = {}
    X_tmp = np.sort(X)
    pct = []
    cnt = 0
    for v in X_tmp:
        if v in mp:
            continue
        else:
            mp[v] = cnt
            cnt+=1
    for v in X:
        pct.append(mp[v]/cnt)
    return pct
```

Calling the function

```
assign_pct([23,4,1,43,1,6])
```

Output of function

```
[0.75, 0.25, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5]
```

Comment: Can you unindent the `def assign_pct(x)` part of the code?

Comment: Corrected the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, all you want to do, is to define the percentile this element represents in the array, how much of the array is before that element. as in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
should be [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]

I believe such code will be enough:

```
def percentileListEdited(List):
    uniqueList = list(set(List))
    increase = 1.0/(len(uniqueList)-1)
    newList = {}
    for index, value in enumerate(uniqueList):
        newList[index] = 0.0 + increase * index
    return [newList[val] for val in List]
```

Comment: Close, but not quite. If I try `percentileList([1,2,3,4,4,5,5])` the list `[0.0, 0.17, 0.33, 0.5, 0.67, 0.83, 0.99]` is returned, where I'd like `[0.0, 0.17, 0.33, 0.50, 0.50, 1.00, 1.00]` returned.

Comment: Well, I want to know more, about what you want to do, the repeating numbers should have the same percentile, but still their percentile are affected by the number of repeated numbers ?!

Comment: Yes, while multiple observations of distinct values should all have the same percentile, each observation still adds to the count of observations that are strictly less than observations with greater values. Percentiles are no quite as straight-forward as some people initially think.

Comment: @Jubbles, indeed they are not. I'll admit to being a bit confused by the example you give above. Having the lowest value be `0.0` _and_ the highest value be `100.0` seems inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks @Aladdin, I like this solution for my problem. Note that it would be nice to generalize it for empty lists and lists with one element (which results in a ZeroDivisionError exception).

Answer (score 1):

For me the best solution is to use `QuantileTransformer` in `sklearn.preprocessing`.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import QuantileTransformer
fn = lambda input_list : QuantileTransformer(100).fit_transform(np.array(input_list).reshape([-1,1])).ravel().tolist()
input_raw = [1, 2, 3, 4, 17]
output_perc = fn( input_raw )

print "Input=", input_raw
print "Output=", np.round(output_perc,2)
```

Here is the output

```
Input= [1, 2, 3, 4, 17]
Output= [ 0.    0.25  0.5   0.75  1.  ]
```

Note: this function has two salient features:

1. input raw data is NOT necessarily sorted.
2. input raw data is NOT necessarily single column.

Answer (score 1):

This version allows also to pass exact percentiles values used to ranking:

```
def what_pctl_number_of(x, a, pctls=np.arange(1, 101)):
    return np.argmax(np.sign(np.append(np.percentile(x, pctls), np.inf) - a))
```

So it's possible to find out what's percentile number value falls for provided percentiles:

```
_x = np.random.randn(100, 1)
what_pctl_number_of(_x, 1.6, [25, 50, 75, 100])
```

Output:

```
3
```

so it hits to 75 ~ 100 range

Answer (score 0):

for a **pure python function** to calculate a **percentile** score for a given item, compared to the population distribution (a list of scores), I pulled this from the `scipy` source code and removed all references to numpy:

```
def percentileofscore(a, score, kind='rank'):    
    n = len(a)
    if n == 0:
        return 100.0
    left = len([item for item in a if item < score])
    right = len([item for item in a if item <= score])
    if kind == 'rank':
        pct = (right + left + (1 if right > left else 0)) * 50.0/n
        return pct
    elif kind == 'strict':
        return left / n * 100
    elif kind == 'weak':
        return right / n * 100
    elif kind == 'mean':
        pct = (left + right) / n * 50
        return pct
    else:
        raise ValueError("kind can only be 'rank', 'strict', 'weak' or 'mean'")
```

source: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.2.1/scipy/stats/stats.py#L1744-L1835

Given that calculating percentiles is trickier than one would think, but way less complicated than the full scipy/numpy/scikit package, this is the best for light-weight deployment. The original code filters for only nonzero-values better, but otherwise, the math is the same. The optional parameter controls how it handles values that are in between two other values.

For this use case, one can call this function for each item in a list using the map() function.