# Does XArray have a function like argmax for quantile statistics?

Tags: python, coordinates, python-xarray, quantile, argmax

Is there a way to keep the coordinates when using xarray.quantile?

I am taking a (90th percentile) quantile of a dataset with coordinates lat, lon, and time.
I want to have the time when the data values are in this quantile.

I run the command Data.quantile([.90],dim='time') which removes the 'time' coordinate and replaces it with 'quantile'
Is there a way to retain the coordinate information AND perform the quantile operation?

There's the argument "keep_attrs" but I have yet to find anything on retaining coordinates.
I want something like xarray.DataArray.argmax

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "keep" the `time` coordinate because the quantiles are calculated over that coordinate.

If you want to return the indices of the computed quantiles along an axis (`time` in your case), there is no `xarray` built-in function such as `argmax`.

However, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26071170/21024780) on a similar question suggests using `np.argpartition` to achieve the task.

The following function I wrote works for `xarray.dataarrays`.

```py
def argquantile(quantiles,darray,dim=None):
    if not isinstance(quantiles,list):
        quantiles = [quantiles]
    if dim is None:
        dim = darray.dims[0]
    idx = [int(np.round(q * (len(darray[dim]) - 1))) for q in quantiles]
    indquant = xr.concat([np.argpartition(darray, [i], axis=darr.dims.index(dim)).isel({dim:i}).drop(dim).assign_coords({'quantile':q}) for i,q in zip(idx,quantiles)],'quantile')
    return indquant
```

It takes similar inputs to the `xarray.DataArray.quantile` built-in function but returns the indices of the quantiles along the selected dimension.

Below there is an example script to test it:

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# The argquantile function
def argquantile(quantiles,darray,dim=None):
    if not isinstance(quantiles,list):
        quantiles = [quantiles]
    if dim is None:
        dim = darray.dims[0]
    idx = [int(np.round(q * (len(darray[dim]) - 1))) for q in quantiles]
    indquant = xr.concat([np.argpartition(darray, [i], axis=darr.dims.index(dim)).isel({dim:i}).drop(dim).assign_coords({'quantile':q}) for i,q in zip(idx,quantiles)],'quantile')
    return indquant

# Let's create an example dataarray
time = np.arange(21)
lat = np.linspace(-90,90,30)
lon = np.linspace(0,360,51)[:-1]
quantiles = [0.5,0.8]
data = np.random.rand(len(time),len(lat),len(lon))
dims = ['time','lat','lon']
coords = [time,lat,lon]
darr = xr.DataArray(data=data, dims = dims, coords={d:coord for d,coord in zip(dims,coords)})

# Calculate quantile with xarray 
# We use interpolation='nearest' so we have exact coordinate values and we can retrieve the exact indices.
q = darr.quantile(quantiles,dim='time',interpolation='nearest')

# Calculate argquantile
aq = argquantile(quantiles,darr,dim='time')

# verify that aq effectively contains the quantiles indeces (for our case)
def verify():
    return np.all([darr[aq[iq,ilat,ilon],ilat,ilon].values == q[iq,ilat,ilon].values for iq,_ in enumerate(quantiles) for ilat,_ in enumerate(lat) for ilon,_ in enumerate(lon)])

print(verify())
```

Hope that helps!

Cheers
Davide

Answer (score 0):

Here is my (terribly inefficient) code:

```
Cape90_by_hour=[]
Cape_by_hour=[]
hours_list=['00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23']
for z in hours_list:
    zhour=CAPE[(CAPE['hour']==z)]
     Cape_by_hour.append(zhour)
     z90=zhour.quantile([.90],dim='hour')
     Cape90_by_hour.append(z90)

cape_above_percentile = []
datetime_of_cape_above_percentile = []

for hr in np.arange(0,24,1):
    percentile_cape = Cape90_by_hour[hr] ['quantile'==1]
    cape90_avg_at_hr=[]
    date_of_cape_above_percentile = []
    for lat_idx in range(len(CAPE1.latitude)):
        for lon_idx in range(len(CAPE1.longitude)):
            percentile_cape90=percentile_cape.isel(latitude=lat_idx,longitude=lon_idx).values
        cape_values = Cape_by_hour[hr].isel(latitude=lat_idx, longitude=lon_idx).values
        time_values = Cape_by_hour[hr]['time']
        cape90_at_each_pt=[]
        dates_at_each_pt=[]
        for w in range(len(cape_values)):
            if cape_values[w] >= percentile_cape90:
                cape90_at_each_pt.append(cape_values[w]) 
                dates_at_each_pt.append(time_values[w])
        cape90_avg=np.sum(cape90_at_each_pt)/len(cape90_at_each_pt)
        cape90_avg_at_hr.append(cape90_avg)
        date_of_cape_above_percentile.append(dates_at_each_pt)
        
cape_above_percentile.append(np.array(cape90_avg_at_hr))
datetime_of_cape_above_percentile.append(np.array(date_of_cape_above_percentile,dtype=object))   

numpts=len(lon)*len(lat)
Cin_at_cape90=[]
for hour in np.arange(0,24,1):
    cin_avg_at_all_pts=[]
    for points in np.arange(0,numpts,1):
        cinValues=[]
        for value in np.arange(0,138,1):
             cinValue=Cin1.isel(latitude=0,longitude=0)[Cin1['time']==datetime_of_cape_above_percentile[hour][points][value]].values                
        cinValues.append(cinValue)
    cin_avg_at_pt=np.nanmean(cinValues)
    cin_avg_at_all_pts.append(cin_avg_at_pt)
cin_avg_at_all_pts2=np.reshape(cin_avg_at_all_pts,(4,4))
Cin_at_cape90.append(cin_avg_at_all_pts2)
```

Let me know if anyone can find a more efficient way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.where()` to filter according to `.quantile()`:

Given an xarray DataArray `da`:

```
>>> da
<xarray.DataArray (time: 100)>
array([-1.11006507e+00, -4.41380179e-01,  1.10087254e+00,  2.18218427e-01,
       ...-5.51287030e-01])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 ... 2000-04-09

>>> da.where(da > da.quantile(0.9, "time"), drop=True)
<xarray.DataArray (time: 10)>
array([1.84009741, 2.25750906, 1.62780955, 1.55448247, 2.11139034,
       2.17723193, 3.11637597, 1.26926648, 1.49876131, 1.55716718])
Coordinates:
  * time      (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-12 2000-01-17 ... 2000-04-03
    quantile  float64 0.9
```

Comment: This does not return the indices of the quantiles.

Comment: If you need the indices, you could use `np.where`: `np.where(da > da.quantile(0.9, "time")) ` yields `array([11, 16, 21, 34, 36, 50, 65, 74, 76, 93]),`

Comment: That returns the indeces of the values greater than those of the quantiles.

Comment: Well, what does he/she want then? xarray's quantile function by default performs a linear interpolation to compute the value of the quantile. Therefore, there will usually not be an element that corresponds exactly to the returned quantile.  Of course, you could say that one is interested, e.g., in the time-index of the nearest value. But that would be quite straight-forward based on my answer I'd say?