# Mean Percentile Ranking (MPR) explanation

Tags: machine-learning, metrics, recommendation-engine

I am trying to use MPR as a metric to evaluate my recommendation system based on implicit feedback. Can somebody please explain MPR? I have gone through this [paper](http://yifanhu.net/PUB/cf.pdf)

However, I can't seem to get an intuitive understanding.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT : I went through [Microsoft's research on metrics for recommendation engine metrics](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/manik/events/xc15/Slides/noam.pdf)

It is recommended that MPR is recommended when we're looking for one 'positive' result. Can somebody also explain why that is the case?

EDIT 2 : [image: Definition of MPR]

Comment: what is the question here ?

Comment: Can I get an intuitive explanatation on MPR? Why is it recommended for a case when we're looking for only one 'positive' result?

Comment: Can you provide a definition of MPR? None of the provided links contain it (from a quick glance).

Comment: Off-topic question - Any particular reason on deleting this [latest question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36771359/implementation-of-mean-percentile-rank-for-recommender-system-with-implicit-feed)? I might have made some headway on it :)

Comment: Hey! Sorry about that. I realized that my question was a bit of a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414043/map-each-list-value-to-its-corresponding-percentile

Comment: Apologies if I wasted your time! I didn't mean to.