# Can we use NDCG as a recommender system metric when the relevance to the recommended item is in binary form?

Tags: precision, metrics, recommendation-engine

Generally there is a relevance associated with item in ndcg calculation but if we only have feedback in 0/1 form. Eg

list ={1,0,0,0,1} when we have recommended 5 items (first and last items are relevant here)
How do we calculate ndcg here ? and does order matters in ndcg evaluation  ?

Also what metrics are useful for evaluation in a binary feedback based recommendation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NDCG@N (Normalized Discounted Comulative Gain) is a ranking measurement for top N position in your ranked output, so yes, the order matters the most here. Look at the good description how to calculate and for better understanding on the example [on the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain). Just just {0,1} as a relevance score.

Other useful measures for evaluating ranked list outputs from recommender systems are: hit ratio (HR@N), recall and precision (REC@N), Mean Recipricol Rank (MRR@N), AUC, [Mean Percentile Rank (MRP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720723/mean-percentile-ranking-mpr-explanation) or for graded relevance (not your case) [Expected Reciprocal Rank (ERR)](http://olivier.chapelle.cc/pub/err.pdf)

Comment: what would IDCG be in the case of recommender system? Imagine for top-5, will we calculate IDCG for [1,1,1,1,1] expecting user to click on all 5?