# Calculating percentile of bins from numpy digitize?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, histogram, percentage

I have a set of data, and a set of thresholds for creating bins:

```
data = np.array([0.01, 0.02, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 8, 8, 4.5, 6.6])
thresholds = np.array([0,5,10])
bins = np.digitize(data, thresholds, right=True)
```

For each of the elements in `bins`, I want to know the base percentile. For example, in `bins`, the smallest bin should start at the 0th percentile. Then the next bin, for example, the 20th percentile. So that if a value in `data` falls between the 0th and 20th percentile of `data`, it belongs in the first `bin`.

I've looked into pandas `rank(pct=True)` but can't seem to get this done correctly.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

You can calculate the percentile for each element in your data array as described in a previous StackOverflow question ([Map each list value to its corresponding percentile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414043/map-each-list-value-to-its-corresponding-percentile#answer-28577101)).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
data = np.array([0.01, 0.02, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 8, 8, 4.5, 6.6])
```

Method 1: Using [scipy.stats.percentileofscore](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html) :

```
data_percentile = np.array([stats.percentileofscore(data, a) for a in data])
data_percentile
Out[1]:
array([  9.09090909,  18.18181818,  36.36363636,  36.36363636,
        36.36363636,  59.09090909,  59.09090909,  95.45454545,
        95.45454545,  72.72727273,  81.81818182])
```

Method 2: Using [scipy.stats.rankdata](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html) and normalising to 100 (faster) :

```
ranked = stats.rankdata(data)
data_percentile = ranked/len(data)*100
data_percentile
Out[2]:
array([  9.09090909,  18.18181818,  36.36363636,  36.36363636,
        36.36363636,  59.09090909,  59.09090909,  95.45454545,
        95.45454545,  72.72727273,  81.81818182])
```

Now that you have a list of percentiles, you can bin them as before using [numpy.digitize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) :

```
bins_percentile = [0,20,40,60,80,100]
data_binned_indices = np.digitize(data_percentile, bins_percentile, right=True)
data_binned_indices
Out[3]:
array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5], dtype=int64)
```

This gives you the data binned according to the indices of your chosen list of percentiles. If desired, you could also return the actual (upper) percentiles using [numpy.take](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) :

```
data_binned_percentiles = np.take(bins_percentile, data_binned_indices)
data_binned_percentiles
Out[4]:
array([ 20,  20,  40,  40,  40,  60,  60, 100, 100,  80, 100])
```