# Mapping each value in a list to its percentile of a different distribution

Tags: python, statistics, distribution

I have a list `scores` and a list `distribution`. I need to map each score in `scores` to what its corresponding percentile would be in `distribution`.

Example:

```
distribution=[4,10,3,5,1]
scores = [1,6,11]
```

The result of the operation should be `[20,80,100]`

[Map each list value to its corresponding percentile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414043/map-each-list-value-to-its-corresponding-percentile)
This similar question has been asked but in my case, making use of scipy.stats.rankdata is not possible because I need to find the percentile of each item in relation to a different distribution.

The natural way to solve it is `[scipy.stats.percentileofscore(distribution,s) for s in scores]` but this is extremely slow when `scores` or `distribution` is large (length higher than about 10,000 for each).

Is there any way to speed this up considerably?  I've tried sorting the distribution list first and then doing a standard search, but the worst case is still quite bad.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `binning`: use your reference distribution as the data set, and the scores as the bin boundaries.  The result will be bins of values from the distribution, such as:

[ [1], [4, 3, 5], [10] ]

You now take the length of each bin (which some binning packages return with the binning lists) and divide by the total distribution population; this gives you incremental percentiles:

```
[0.20, 0.60, 0.20]
```

From here, the cumulative sum is trivial

```
[0.20, 0.80, 1.0]
```

Does that get you moving?