# Inverse of np.percentile()

Tags: python, numpy

For a given vector `x`, I would like to provide a value (say `np.mean(x)`) and I am looking for the percentile this value falls in. Any such built in numpy function or easy way to implement it?

Comment: Did you look throught the documentation?

Comment: @wwiiu unfortunately yes. Found this: scipy.stats.percentileofscore but I am looking to stick to numpy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29989971/5351549