# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'percentile'

Tags: python, numpy, percentile

I use this function to calculate percentile  from [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html):

```
import numpy as np
a = [12, 3, 45, 0, 45, 47, 109, 1, 0, 3]
np.percentile(a, 25)
```

But I get this error :

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'percentile'
```

I also tried

```
import numpy.percentile as np
```

but it didn't I got the same error.

my numpy version is 1.3.0 I tried to upgrade but it seems like it won't I used : `[sudo pip install --upgrade scipy][2]` but I found that there's no upgrade.

my ubuntu version 9.10

my python version is : 2.6.4

i also tried to go arround the numpy.percentile module and I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374640/how-do-i-calculate-percentiles-with-python-numpy):

```
>>> def percentile(N, P):
...     n = int(round(P * len(N) + 0.5))
...     if n > 1:
...         return N[n-2]
...     else:
...         return 0
...
>>> a = [1, 23, 5, 45, 676, 2, 0, 4,3]
>>> a = sorted(a)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 23, 45, 676]
#When I call the function using 
>>> percentile(a,0.5)
3
```

but when I tried to find `0.5 percentile` manually I found `5`

Can anyone help explain to me why this is happening in any of those cases?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `percentile` function was added in [version 1.5.x](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.5.x/numpy/lib/function_base.py). You will need to upgrade to at least that version.

Did you try:

```
sudo pip install numpy==1.7.1 --upgrade
```

To check which version you are running, start the python console and run:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> print numpy.__version__
```

You can also do:

```
sudo pip freeze | grep numpy
```

The Ubuntu 9.10 numpy package uses [version 1.3.03](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/karmic/i386/python-numpy). It is likely that installing version 1.7.0 vai pip was successful, but your machine is defaulting to the python-numpy version instead. You can remove by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-numpy
```

Comment: Thanks  alot for your replay and the link . No I didn't try `sudo pip install numpy==1.7.1 --upgrade`, but I just did, and i still get the same error message.

Comment: the version is `1.3.0`, mean that the upgrade won't happened.

Comment: Uninstall that version using `sudo apt-get remove python-numpy`

Comment: done! do you recommend using `apt-get install python-numpy` to install numpy?

Comment: I would if you were using a recent version of Ubuntu, but you are using 9.10 which uses a very old (likely 1.3.0) version of numpy.

Comment: any idea how to install a newer version?

Comment: You will need to install a newer version using pip. I would guess it is already installed and that you had two versions before.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28281/discussion-between-mongotop-and-nathan-villaescusa)

Comment: removing and reinstaling numpy and I changed  `import numpy.percentile` with  `from numpy import percentile`  and that done the job

Answer (score 2):

Please upgrade your numpy package

```
pip install --upgrade numpy==1.19.1
```

or

```
sudo pip install --upgrade numpy==1.19.1
```