# How to compute percentiles from frequency table?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, statistics

I have CSV file:

```
fr id
 1 10000152
 1 10000212
 1 10000847
 1 10001018
 2 10001052
 2 10001246
14 10001908
...........
```

This is a frequency table, where `id` is integer variable and `fr` is number of occurrences given value. File is sorted ascending by value.
I would like to compute percentiles (ie. 90%, 80%, 70% ... 10%) of variable.

I have done this in pure Python, similar to this pseudocode:

```
bucket=sum(fr)/10.0
percentile=1
sum=0
for (current_fr, current_id) in zip(fr,id):
   sum=sum+current_fr
   if (sum > percentile*bucket):
      print "%i percentile: %i" % (percentile*10,current_id)
      percentile=percentile+1
```

But this code is very raw: it doesn't take into account that percentile should be between values from the set, it can't step back etc.

Is there any more elegant, universal, ready-made solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want cumulative sum of `fr`. You can do

```
cumfr = [sum(fr[:i+1]) for i in range(len(fr))]
```

Then the percentiles are

```
percentile = [100*i/cumfr[-1] for i in cumfr]
```

Comment: This is a good answer with limited explanation. It might help more people if a better explanation was given. Also, I am not able to correct the fr(:i+1) to fr[:i+1]. Can someone with permissions to change less than 6 characters make that change? The error thrown by Python is misleading while running the code.