# Find percentile stats of a given column

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, quantile, percentile

I have a `pandas` data frame `my_df`, where I can find the mean(), median(), mode() of a given column:

```
my_df['field_A'].mean()
my_df['field_A'].median()
my_df['field_A'].mode()
```

I am wondering is it possible to find more detailed statistics such as the 90th percentile?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

- You can use the [`pandas.DataFrame.quantile()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) function.

  - If you look at the API for `quantile()`, you will see it takes an argument for how to do interpolation. If you want a quantile that falls between two positions in your data:

    - 'linear', 'lower', 'higher', 'midpoint', or 'nearest'.
    - By default, it performs linear interpolation.
    - These interpolation methods are discussed in the Wikipedia article for [percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample data 
np.random.seed(2023)  # for reproducibility
data = {'Category': np.random.choice(['hot', 'cold'], size=(10,)),
        'field_A': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10,)),
        'field_B': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10,))}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.field_A.mean()  # Same as df['field_A'].mean()
# 51.1

df.field_A.median() 
# 50.0

# You can call `quantile(i)` to get the i'th quantile,
# where `i` should be a fractional number.

df.field_A.quantile(0.1)  # 10th percentile
# 15.6

df.field_A.quantile(0.5)  # same as median
# 50.0

df.field_A.quantile(0.9)  # 90th percentile
# 88.8

df.groupby('Category').field_A.quantile(0.1)
#Category
#cold    28.8
#hot      8.6
#Name: field_A, dtype: float64
```

#### `df`

```
  Category  field_A  field_B
0     cold       96       58
1     cold       22       28
2      hot       17       81
3     cold       53       71
4     cold       47       63
5      hot       77       48
6     cold       39       32
7      hot       69       29
8      hot       88       49
9      hot        3       49
```

Answer (score 39):

assume series `s`

```
s = pd.Series(np.arange(100))
```

Get quantiles for `[.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9]`

```
s.quantile(np.linspace(.1, 1, 9, 0))

0.1     9.9
0.2    19.8
0.3    29.7
0.4    39.6
0.5    49.5
0.6    59.4
0.7    69.3
0.8    79.2
0.9    89.1
dtype: float64
```

OR

```
s.quantile(np.linspace(.1, 1, 9, 0), 'lower')

0.1     9
0.2    19
0.3    29
0.4    39
0.5    49
0.6    59
0.7    69
0.8    79
0.9    89
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 17):

I figured out below would work:

```py
my_df.dropna().quantile([0.0, .9])
```

Answer (score 16):

You can even give multiple columns with null values and get multiple quantile values (I use 95 percentile for outlier treatment)

```
my_df[['field_A','field_B']].dropna().quantile([0.0, .5, .90, .95])
```

Answer (score 8):

a very easy and efficient way is to call the describe function on the particular column

```
df['field_A'].describe()
```

this will give you the mean ,max ,median and the 75th percentile

Answer (score 8):

Describe will give you quartiles, if you want percentiles, you can do something like

```
 df['YOUR_COLUMN_HERE'].describe(percentiles=[.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6 , .7, .8, .9, 1])
```