# Quantile values for each column in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, quantile

I have a dataframe which consists of columns of numbers.  I am trying to calc the decile rank values for each column.  The following code gives me the values for the dataframe as a whole.  How can I do it by column?

```
pd.qcut(df, 10, labels=False)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related: [pandas find percentile stats of a given column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581893/pandas-find-percentile-stats-of-a-given-column)

Answer (score 1):

If you apply **qcut** across the columns you will get a dataframe where each entry is the rank value.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data_a = np.random.random(100)
data_b = 100*np.random.random(100)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B'], data=list(zip(data_a, data_b)))
rank = df.apply(pd.qcut, axis=0, q=10, labels=False)
```