# Pandas.. does quantile function need sorted data to calculate percentiles?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm using Pandas to clean up some data and do basic statistics. I am wondering if `quantile()` does sort the values before the calculation or i must do the sorting beforehand?

For example, here I'm trying to get the 50th percentile of the number of workers in each company

```
Percentile50th = Y2015_df.groupby (["company"])["worker"].quantile(0.50)
```

I'm asking because when I was verifying the values I got with the results in  MS Excel, I discovered that Median function requires the data to be sorted in order to get the right median. But I'm not sure if its the case in Pandas.

Comment: No.
Take a look at this.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45495773/9136398)

Comment: @Parth By no you mean it does not need any sorting from my side right? the function does the all the work.. just wanted to double-check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to sort. See the link in my previous comment. [Example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-quantile/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Parth