# What gem to use to calculate percentile in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sciruby

In python, I can do this by using python, as in [How do I calculate percentiles with python/numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374640/how-do-i-calculate-percentiles-with-python-numpy)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
p = np.percentile(a, 50)
```

I want to know what is the convenient way in 2018 to calculate percentile in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is few lines function, developer can write it by his own in 2018.
But you can check [descriptive_statistics](https://github.com/thirtysixthspan/descriptive_statistics) gem.

```
require 'descriptive_statistics'
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
data.percentile(50)
```

Comment: I've already implemented my own approach, but I always think to put it into some module like numpy would by much better.